# Como adicionar uma fonte externa num SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, font

Eu tenho uma logo que fiz em `SVG`, em arquivo `.svg`externo, que usa tem um texto com o nome da empresa, cuja a fonte é `Open Sans Light`.

Na minha máquina funciona normalmente, devido ao fato de eu ter a fonte instalada.

Eu tenho essa fonte no meu site através do *Google Fonts*, porém, creio que pelo fato de o SVG está sendo carregado externamente, através da propriedade `background-image`, essa fonte não está funcionando.

Como faço para declarar essa fonte externa dentro do SVG? Existe alguma forma de fazer isso...

Por exemplo, como eu poderia fazer isso no SVG abaixo?

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
   <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   <text y="105" x="85" style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
     <tspan>Text</tspan>
   </text>
 </svg>
```

*Nota*: Apesar do meu exemplo estar em HTML, eu estou usando um arquivo SVG externo.

Comment: Estou precisando adicionar uma fonte externa no meu notebook :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O SVG tem suporte para CSS, claro que com algumas propriedades diferentes para os elementos, no caso pode usar `@font-face` e vai conseguir o desejado, por exemplo:

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
</style>
```

Um teste:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
    </style>
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
    <text y="105" x="85" style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;">
        <tspan>Text</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

No entanto devo dizer que usar `<text>` em SVG só é interessante quando o texto é "dinâmico" (que altere dinamicamente), se for usar textos estáticos, o ideal seria vetoriza-los, assim torna mais performático, tanto pelo tempo de download quanto pelo tempo de renderização.

---

### Extra

Note que existe (existiu) as tags para SVG:

- `<font-face-format>`
- `<font-face-name>`
- `<font-face-src>`
- `<font-face-uri>`
- `<font-face>`

No entanto estão em desuso (são obsoletas).

---

### Como vetorizar texto no Inkscape

Selecione o texto, sem o grupo (no rodapé como na imagem, deve aparecer **Texto** ou **Text**, se aparecer outra coisa é porque não selecionou o `<text>`):

[image: Exemplo no Inkscape]

Então vá no menu superior e selecione <kbd>Caminho</kbd> > <kbd>Converter em caminho</kbd> (ou segure <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)

---

### Como vetorizar texto Adobe Illustrator CC

> Não sei como fazer em outras versões, pode funcionar em mais antigas ou não, por favor comentem

Selecione o texto e então no menu selecione <kbd>Type</kbd> > <kbd>Create outlines</kbd>